# Как правильно оформить навигацию при сужении окна на CSS

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, media-queries

Привет! У меня возникла проблема с попыткой создать адаптированное меню.

Пункты меню сделаны через inline-block и идут в одну строку. При сужении окна браузера, если места не хватает, они переносятся. Но border у них остается. И когда очередной пункт в меню переносится, смотрится это некрасиво - слева border, а отделять нечего. Как решить эту проблему?

У меня на уме разве что через media отслеживать когда переносятся пункты меню и удалять у них border. Но, по-моему, не самое лучшее решение. Много media. И, кстати, еще вопрос - я никогда не натягивал верстку на CMS. Но может ли быть такое, что заказчик переименует пункты? Или изменит padding'и у них? Если да, то мое решение точно не подходит.

Код: https://jsfiddle.net/wzdn6rmq/

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
    <a href="#" class="menu-item">One</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu-item">Two</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu-item">Three</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu-item">Four</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu-item">Five</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu-item">Six</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menu {text-align: center;}

.menu-item {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 30px; 
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
.menu-item:first-child {border: none;}
```

Comment: Лучше приведите пример исходного кода страницы, ваш вопрос могут закрыть за то что очень общий, немного конкретнее (хотя мне ваш вопрос нравится). Пишите не `Подскажите наилучший способ решения данной проблемы` (вопросы-опросники запрещены), пишите `Как решить данную проблему?`. Тогда вас не закроют. (Да и текст разбивайте на абзацы (двойной Enter) )

Comment: Постарайтесь конкретнее изложить вопрос и используя меньше слов

Comment: Идея есть, но с кроссбраузерностью проблемы...

Comment: Мне кажется такие проблемы это все же в первую очередь проблемы дизайна, соответственно решать как мне кажется нужно с другой стороны

Answer (score 2):

Лучше всего сделать группами на Media Queries:

1. Для десктопа всё в одну строку
2. Для планшетов в 2 строки, разбить на 2 части по 3 штуки (для этого можно разбить на 2 скрытых группы
3. Для мобил в колонку по одному пункту.

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/uzqr2e5q/

```
<div class="menu">
    <span class="group">
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Menu</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Menu</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Menu</a>
    </span>
    <span class="group">
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Menu</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Menu</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Menu</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

И примерно такой CSS:

```
.menu {
    text-align: center;
}

.menu-item {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    background: #ccc;
}


@media (min-width: 500px) {
    .group {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .menu-item {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px 30px;   
        background: #fff;
    }

    .group .menu-item + .menu-item {
        border-left: 1px solid #000;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
    .group {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .menu-item {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px 30px;   
        background: #fff;
        border-right: 1px solid #000;
    }

    .group .menu-item + .menu-item {
        border-left: 0;
    }

    .group:last-child .menu-item:last-child {
        border-right: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Но может ли быть такое, что заказчик переименует пункты? Или изменит padding'и у них?

Это почти обязательно случится:)
Наверное, лучший способ - берите медиа-запросы и уменьшайте размер пунктов так, чтобы они были в одну строку, причем с небольшим запасом. Когда ширина экрана станет достаточно маленькой - делайте пункты в 2/3 ряда, или прячьте их под кнопку.